# How to read a file in my local storage as in memory and attach it into email?

Tags: python, django, file-handling, django-email

This snippet is to generate an xlsx file and then attach that file into an email
Note: I'm not saving any file, it is in memory.

```
import io
a = io.BytesIO()
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
import xlsxwriter
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(a, {'in_memory': True})
worksheet_s = workbook.add_worksheet('abcd')
worksheet_s.write(0, 0, 'Hello, world!')
workbook.close()
a.seek(0)
email = EmailMessage('Subject', 'Body', 'sentby@mailinator.com', ['sentto@mailinator.com'])
email.attach('file.xlsx', a.getvalue())
email.send()
```

Similarly to this, I want to attach a file in my storage to email but first want to open it in in memory.
 As I am Trying to write a generic code to send Email from one place whether it has attachments(self-generated file or file in storage) or not.

Something like this

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
file = open('file.jpeg')
email = EmailMessage('Subject', 'Body', 'sendedby@mailinator.com', ['sentto@mailinator.com'])
email.attach(file.name, file.getvalue())
email.send()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I see you don't want to save your file - only in memory. Then you can use this example. Also you need install **openpyxl**

```
from openpyxl.writer.excel import save_virtual_workbook
from openpyxl import Workbook
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
email = EmailMessage('Subject', 'Body', 'sentby@mailinator.com', ['sentto@mailinator.com'])
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws['A1'] = 42
file = save_virtual_workbook(wb)
email.attach('file_name.xlsx', file)
email.send()
```

Comment: This is not what I want. What I asked is how to open an existing file of any extension into memory so that I can use "email.attach(file.name, file.getvalue())"

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function like this to send an email with an attachment, be it a file on disk or a BytesIO object with in-memory content:

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
import io

def send_email_with_attachment(file_name, file_content):
    email = EmailMessage('Subject', 'Body', 'sendedby@mailinator.com', 
        ['sentto@mailinator.com'])
    file_content.seek(0)
    email.attach(file_name, file_content.read())
    email.send()

# use it with a "regular" on-disk file
file = open('file.jpeg', 'rb')
send_email_with_attachment('file.jpeg', file)

# use it with a BytesIO object
a = io.BytesIO()
# do something to populate the BytesIO with content, i.e. create an Excel file in memory
send_email_with_attachment('file.xlsx', a)
```

Consider also that Django EmailMessage class provides a method to attach files directly from filesystem:

```
email.attach_file(filepath)
```

You can refer to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/email/#emailmessage-objects) for more information.